# Why am I asked to open YouTube videos in VLC?

Tags: ios, safari, youtube

I use the mobile site for YouTube in safari on iOS 13.3. Sometimes when I tap play on a video I get a pop up saying 'Open in "VLC"?' as though I had ever made the slightest indication of wanting that.

When I tap cancel I'm left with a non playing video in safari.

How do I disable this nonsense? What's causing it? Is VLC now affiliated with YouTube, or if not, how do I prevent it from infiltrating the domain and interfering with my browsing?

Comment: Can you share a link for one such video?

Comment: @NimeshNeema This one has the described symptoms at the time of writing: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xp1DE3dMNoM

Comment: Only when in YouTube's phone layout. Tablet and desktop layouts can play the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most probably caused by having played around with "Request Desktop Site" in Safari, whereby I somehow end up getting served a mobile page, but with an unsupported video format (likely VP9).